# Half star not aligned with the rest

Tags: html, css

I'm implementing this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GYRajr) snippet on my site and noticed that the half-star is not aligned with the rest. It's only a very small difference but I notice it and it bugs me. The other thing I noticed was that the orange portion of the half-star doesn't start at the beginning of the star: there's a little bit of gray before the orange part. You may have to zoom in a bit to see these things.

I've tried messing with the `top` and `left` values as well as `line-height` in the CSS, but none of that works. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to fix this or am I stuck?

```css
.glyphicon-star {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #e67e22;
}
.glyphicon-star.half {
  position: relative;
}
.glyphicon-star.half:before {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 47%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.glyphicon-star.half:after {
  content: '\e006';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 8;
  color: #bdc3c7;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="rating">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star half"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `vertical-align: top;` to `.glyphicon-star`

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you! Also, props to @Ori Drori for the edit. I should have included the code directly in my question.

Comment: is the little grey part at the beginning of your star solved too ?

Comment: Using little SVG stars for this would be much more robust - for cross-browser issues / and in general - would be much easier to control. Give it a try!

Comment: @MattR - you're welcome. I've also added an answer.

Comment: It doesn't solve the grey part problem but Ori Drori's answer below does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of limiting the width and using `overflow: hidden`, you can use [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to draw a silver half star on the right side. You won't need to vertically align the half star, and it also solves the missing point on the left side:

```css
.glyphicon-star {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #e67e22;
}

.glyphicon-star.half::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 8;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #bdc3c7;
  content: '\e006';
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 47%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="rating">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star half"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! This works and solves the missing point issue like you said.